# ec2-user password for running sudo -H -u

Tags: amazon-ec2, password, sudo, git

I have to run this command to initialize [gitosis](https://github.com/res0nat0r/gitosis):

```
sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < /home/ec2-user/id_rsa.pub
```

But that asks me for a password for ec2-user:

```
$ sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < id_rsa.pub
[sudo] password for ec2-user:
```

I do not have a password as i use the default .pem key file to login.

I know i can probably login as the git user and do this, but is there any other way?

**Update:**

Using Linux AMI 12.09 (micro-instance), in region us-east-1 (N. Virginia)

Comment: should i move this question to superuser or stackoverflow or somewhere else?

Comment: What EC2 region are you running in?  What AMI id did you start with?

Comment: @EricHammond please see update. I do have a workaround, see answer, but still looking for a better solution if possible, not sure if the workaround is best possible solution here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you discovered, the `root` user can `sudo` to any other user, so just stick an extra `sudo` in front.

```
sudo sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < /home/ec2-user/id_rsa.pub
```

Please don't kick yourself too hard.

Comment: i'll try not to :) . didn't know you could do that actually, awesome.

Answer (score 2):

This is my current workaround:

1. First login as *ec2-user* with the .pem file
2. Then switch to *root* with `sudo su`
3. Then switch to *git* user with `su git`
4. Then run the `gitosis-init` like so:

   ```
   gitosis-init < path/to/id_rsa.pub
   ```
5. `exit` from *git* user, then `exit` from *root*.

---

Note: I had added the *git* user with just `sudo adduser git`

Answer (score 1):

You want to update `/etc/sudoers` to allow you to run commands as `git` without requiring a password.

First, edit the `sudoers` file:

```
$ EDITOR=my_favorite_text_editor sudo -E visudo
```

Add the following line at the end*:

```
ec2_user  ALL=(git) NOPASSWD: gitosis-init
```

You can then use the command that you've been using, but you will no longer be prompted for a password.

---

* Or you can add that to a file in `/etc/sudoers.d`, if you have that available.

Comment: awesome, i did read something like this while searching for a solution but was unsure (_then_) if it'll work, good alternate method, thanx.